# WPF disabling only a certain group of buttons

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I disable a group of buttons, but not all of them? I want to disable a certain group of let's say 10 buttons, but still be able to click the remaining 3.
The buttons I want to disable will be simply named button1, button2 and so on.

Comment: Bind their `IsEnabled` property to a single property in your view model.

Comment: @Jar.jar do you mean to disable the buttons when some event ocurres?

Comment: @Nehorai Yes, to be precise I want to make a button that when clicked disables the said group

Answer (score 0):

You can use data binding for that purpose:

as you can see in the following example, I created a small class that manage different buttons groups:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ButtonGroupsController MyButtonGroups = new ButtonGroupsController();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = MyButtonGroups;
        MyButtonGroups.Group1Enable = false;
        MyButtonGroups.Group2Enable = true;

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyButtonGroups.Group1Enable = !MyButtonGroups.Group1Enable;
        MyButtonGroups.Group2Enable = !MyButtonGroups.Group2Enable;
    }
}

public class ButtonGroupsController : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool group1Enable = false;
    private bool group2Enable = false;

    public bool Group1Enable
    {
        get
        {
            return group1Enable;
        }
        set
        {
            group1Enable = value;
            if (PropertyChanged!=null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Group1Enable"));
            }
        }
    }
    public bool Group2Enable
    {
        get
        {
            return group2Enable;
        }
        set
        {
            group2Enable = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Group2Enable"));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

and the XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
        <Button  IsEnabled="{Binding Group1Enable , Mode=OneWay}" Click="Button_Click">click me</Button>
        <Button IsEnabled="{Binding Group1Enable, Mode=OneWay}" Click="Button_Click">click me</Button>
        <Button IsEnabled="{Binding Group1Enable, Mode=OneWay}" Click="Button_Click">click me</Button>
        <Button  IsEnabled="{Binding Group2Enable, Mode=OneWay }" Click="Button_Click">click me</Button>
        <Button IsEnabled="{Binding Group2Enable, Mode=OneWay}" Click="Button_Click">click me</Button>
        <Button IsEnabled="{Binding Group2Enable, Mode=OneWay}" Click="Button_Click">click me</Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To simulate your scenario I created a list of ten buttons which all get names similar to the names of your buttons:

```
// create some buttons for simulation purposes, give them a name and put them into a list
var buttons = new List<Button>();    
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    var button = new Button();
    button.Name = "button" + i;
    buttons.Add(button);
}
```

To disable a button you can use the `IsEnabled` property as it was mentioned by Clemens in the comments above:

```
// option A: disable all buttons except button at index 2 
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Count; ++i)
{
    if (i == 2)
    {
        continue;
    }

    buttons[i].IsEnabled = false;
}


// option b: disable all buttons except button with name 'button3'
foreach (var button in buttons)
{
    if (button.Name == "button3")
    {
        continue;
    }

    button.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

To get the buttons of your current window you could use this little helper method ...

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); ++i)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like ...

```
List<Button> buttons = FindVisualChildren<Button>(<< enter parent-object of the buttons here >>).ToList();
```

If the parent is the window, you can use:

```
List<Button> buttons = FindVisualChildren<Button>(this).ToList();
```

If the parent is a grid that with the name 'MyGrid', you can use:

```
List<Button> buttons = FindVisualChildren<Button>(this.MyGrid).ToList();
```